# Separating Developer(Admin) app version and normal version

Tags: c#

I'm writing this application where I want the (Admin - Developer) have more control of the app than the "regular" users. Let's say, a button will only be shown to the Admin if a setting is enabled.

So I was wondering about how to make 2 different versions? Only way I can think of right now is to first write the "regular" and release it, then re-add the code/features I want the admin to have.

Maybe a setting somewhere or something that can be enabled/disabled during publish that can make life easier? Any help/tips will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I've just set a setting in the Settings panel (Setting True/False) and using the Properties to allow/disallow features. If anyone knows of a better way please reply!

Answer (score 0):

First you should clearly identify the tasks of the administrators for example user related tasks like creating users, deleting users, giving permissions, resetting passwords and configuring database connections may fall in to this category. Then you can create a separate set of interfaces/ windows to handle this tasks, you should enable these only when an admin is logged in. That is the easiest way to do it. After you have identified the admin features you have the option of creating a separate app for the admins as well.

And if you have some features which you can't separate out of the regular forms like if you have button in a regular form which only gets enabled for specific user I think you should use settings based approach.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how significant the UI differences are between the two user groups. 
Generally, you want to maintain the least amount of code, so the drive is to avoid code duplication, so you won't have to maintain three files with the same logic or ui elements in them. (I assume ASP.NET: User controls are really good to deal with this.)

Second, do not make logical decisions on who the user is, but rather abstract it out and base logic on what a role can do (i.e. permissions). For instance: when processing a page and hiding/showing elements, base the decision to show the "delete" link if the user has the "DELETE" permission.